# 2 column nav dropdown

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation menu and I want the dropdown links to be in two separate columns.

I've tried using the columns property of CSS and have played around with other recommendations I have found online.

The html:

```
<nav id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li>
    <a href="#" class="arrow">Services</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="service1.html"><img src="images/icon_service1.png" alt="Service1" />Service 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="service2.html"><img src="images/icon_service2.png" alt="Service2" />Service 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#" class="arrow">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="about1.html"><img src="images/icon_about1.png" alt="About1" />About 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

I tried to post the CSS but kept getting an error that it wasn't indented properly with 4 spaces...?  I'll try to post it in the comments...

The JS:

Dropdowns.

> $('#nav > ul').dropotron({
>       offsetY: -16,
>       mode: 'fade',
>       noOpenerFade: true,
>       hideDelay: 400
>   });

The menu is displaying as a single dropdown and I want to show it as two columns.

I would preferably like to have it show two columns if there are 8 or more items in the drop down preferably, but I could set the css separately if need be.

I have tried css Columns but nothing I've tried has worked.

I'm attaching the CSS as images because the editor won't seem to let me add CSS...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeOsF.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S49zX.jpg)

Comment: Using a code snippet for this question would be nice :)

Comment: Did you try to _display_ your dropdown as a _grid_ with 2 columns ?

Comment: Please never use screenshots of your code!

Comment: I couldn't get the editor to let me post the code.  All I get when I try to post the CSS is a message that it can't be posted because it's formatted improperly (which clearly isn't correct)...

I posted pictures because I figured that would be better than nothing.  

I just tried again and I get this error: "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.", which is clearly not accurate. Thanks again!